# Could we know what's the total number of unsatisfiable 3SAT formulas for a given n variables?

Tags: satisfiability, p-vs-np, 3-sat

given some $n$ variables I would be interested to know what is the count of all 3SAT formulas under $n$ that are unsatisfiable.

An example of all 3SAT forumlas under $n=3$ is the following:
$$
( x \lor y \lor z) = Satisfiable
\\ ...
\\
( x \lor y \lor z)\land ( \neg x \lor \neg y \lor z)= Satisfiable
\\ ...
\\ 
( x \lor y \lor z)\land( x \lor y \lor \neg z).....( \neg x \lor \neg y \lor \neg z) = Unsatisfiable
$$
The total count of $n=3$ would be 1, because only the last formula is actually unsatisfiable

as you can see, even with a small number such as $n=3$ there are 256 different formulas, going even a single digit up to $n=4$ will result in $2^{32}$ different formulas, so it cannot be simulated.

Therefor I was wondering, is there any way of knowing just the count without having to check it one by one?

Comment: are you interested in exact answers, or approximate is sufficient?

Comment: There are some interesting asymptotic bounds: If you draw a 3SAT formula randomly with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses, almost all with $\frac{m}{n}> 4.267$ are unsatisfiable, and almost all with $ \frac{m}{n}<4.267$ are satisfiable. You can easily calculate the number of these. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86544/44709

Comment: What does it mean for a formula to be "under $n$"?

Comment: Have you checked https://oeis.org/?

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki although not exactly answering it does provide interesting and valuable insight, thank you